# Windows 8 Live Tile Icon Background Color

Tags: wpf, windows-8, window, icons

I am developing a WPF application. My customers want to use it on Windows 8 and it's working correctly. But they are complaining me about the background color of the app's icon on Start Screen.

So can you please show me how to change it in Visual Studio or some tricks? I found some tuts on Google to customize it but using tools and I want to make it happen in Installer or Property of project...

Thanks[image]

Answer (score 3):

Change app icon color from the App Manifest file.

Heres the app manifest portion where you can change in the image

[image: App tile background]

In My case the bacground color is #464646 you can change it to any thing you want and update to the users :)

Because of this reason it is always advised by Microsoft to use Transparent Png logo and a uniform background color for app tile.

Comment: So do I have to make an Manifest setting in Property of current project?

Comment: No just go ahead and add the Images to the respective snall logo , wide logo source. App will itself detect the images and let you select tiles and change shapes on right click or drag down in surface. Make sure you upload the relevant size image as mentioned in the scale :)

Comment: really? Can we do it with normal WPF application?

Comment: you cannot create a custom tile for a store app. but indow forms give you an oppurtunity to create even theres a software that helps creating the xaml tile. i am not that much in to win forms but have some idea. For windows store app you have to provide a tile from here only :) But you can go for win forms Ill share the software link

Comment: Heres the link http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/modern-all-the-way-creating-custom-tiles-for-windows-8/

Answer (score 0):

That background colot of app's icon on Windows 8 is the default behavior of Windows 8. It will display the background color of the app's icon using the "dominant" color of the app's icon. If your icon has dominant color of brown, it will display brown background.

This is also the similar default behavior when hovering mouse on running application's icons on Windows 7's taskbar. To enhance the look, try change the application icon to use neutral colors or light colors instead of dark colors.

Or you can change the icon of your app to use single color's icon (such as white) on transparent background to reflect the flat theme icons of Windows Store apps in Windows 8, or use full rectangle icons as those games in Windows 8.

Example:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Eriawan but my app is just a normal Windows 7 WPF application. And I can see some apps have diferent backgroun color but not sure if it's an option for Windows Store App only.

Comment: No. Every normal Windows 7 Desktop app will be treated as Windows 8 Desktop app if you install it on Windows 8. This include WPF, Windows Forms. Only those Windows Store app will have desired background and you can also customize icon background too, Microsoft calls it "tile".
Therefore your desktop app can't choose background because of the behavior I've described in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar question and answer: [UWP Tile Background Color Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36503505/uwp-tile-background-color-not-working) by [Kasper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3987526/kasper), but is not specific to Windows 8, for anyone looking for a UWP solution.

As the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18805014/7921646) by [Anobik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1603313/anobik) states, set the colour in the app manifest page. However, as it was found by [Kasper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3987526/kasper), **the value must be set in *HEX*** for it to work as expected.