# How to change windows 8 live tile text color?

Tags: windows-8, winrt-xaml

I am creating a windows 8 application in which I want to change foreground of live tile. I Have found a [set of templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh761491.aspx#medium_peek_templates) but didn't find any way to change live tile's text color.

[image: I want to cannge color of text which is shown on the live tile]

I have written following template code in my application.

```
<tile>
    <visual>
        <binding template=""TileWidePeekImage01"">
            <image id=""1"" src=""{0}"" alt=""alt text""/>
            <text id=""1"">ActySystem</text>
            <text id=""2"">{1} Updated: {2} {3}</text>
        </binding>
    </visual>
</tile>
```

Please Help me!

Comment: See if this is of any use http://stackoverflow.com/q/18755773/1654121

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have only two choice for live tile text color, white & black. Have you ever seen any live tile text with red or blue foreground, then let me see, I am desperate.

[image]

[image]

[image]