# How can I specify the text color for a pinned site tile?

Tags: web-applications, windows-8, windows-10, microsoft-edge, pinned-site

I have a web app, I'd like to make into a [pinnable website](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg491738). It currently has the following in its `<head>` element:

```
<meta name="application-name" content="MyWebApp">
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#666666">
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="/images/favicons/mstile-144x144.png">
<meta name="msapplication-config" content="/images/favicons/browserconfig.xml">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
```

And the `browserconfig.xml` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<browserconfig>
  <msapplication>
    <tile>
      <square70x70logo src="/images/favicons/mstile-70x70.png"/>
      <square150x150logo src="/images/favicons/mstile-150x150.png"/>
      <square310x310logo src="/images/favicons/mstile-310x310.png"/>
      <wide310x150logo src="/images/favicons/mstile-310x150.png"/>
      <TileColor>#666666</TileColor>
    </tile>
  </msapplication>
</browserconfig>
```

However the tile currently displays with very dark text, rather than white text.

My problem is similar to [How to change windows 8 live tile text color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19026005/how-to-change-windows-8-live-tile-text-color), except that's for native apps, this is for for web apps.

A [similar question on MSDN](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-desktop/need-ability-to-set-tile-text-color-through-meta/10a19e0b-1303-47ec-8d6b-3670aa16e4e4) has no answers.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a way to do it for Web apps. Although it can be done in `*.VisualElementsManifest.xml` on the desktop side with the [`ForegroundText` property](http://www.askvg.com/tip-customize-start-screen-tiles-background-color-text-color-and-logo-in-windows-8-1/), If you look at the [Pinned site metadata reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Dn255024(v=VS.85).aspx), there is no mention of an equivalent property for `browserconfig.xml`.

This seems like an oversight; maybe if enough of us let [support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us) know about the issue, they'll change it.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, the color of the text depends on the color of the background and it can only be white or black.
[Build My Pinned Site](http://www.buildmypinnedsite.com/en) should have the right logic to know what color the text is going to be. I built it a while ago so maybe some of the logic has change but I doubt it.