# UWP Tile Text Color

Tags: winrt-xaml, win-universal-app, windows-10

I am trying to set the text color on my UWP app's primary Start Menu tile so that it is black. (I am doing this because my app's icon calls for a white background, and you cannot see white text on a white background.) I found [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19026005/how-to-change-windows-8-live-tile-text-color), but it discusses Windows 8 apps, and the UI described in the answer does not seem to exist anymore when developing for Windows 10. Does anyone know how to do this on a Windows 10 UWP app?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way of doing this in a UWP app has changed slightly. Set the `ForegroundText` attribute to `"dark"` in the [`VisualElements`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211471.aspx) node.